# Please ensure that NPM is installed or configure 'typescript.npm' in your user settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been using VSCode for some time for php (laravel) and grails (groovy/java) projects, and like it.

Out of the blue, the above error message popped up.

If I understand correctly, it is saying:

1. installing node and npm is a pre-requisite to using VSCode with JS.
2. I have to manually configure VScode to know where node is.
3. I need to manually modify my projects source code to include lodash (i.e. change my source code for the benefit of the IDE?)

What I would like to understand is:

1. Why VSCode didnt install node automatically for me if it is a pre-requisit?
2. Why this has only just started being a problem?
3. What is the downside if I dont go through this installation and configuration work?  I don't know if the type stuff would actually be relevant to my project (Which does use JS).
4. According to the docs, VSCode uses typescript to do the type magic.  But typescript is built into VSCode, so why does it need node?

Sorry for all the questions, Trying to work out if getting rid of this constant warning message is worth the pain.

Answer (score 0):

Npm is used for automatic type acquisition (ATA) which powers our JavaScript IntelliSense. This warning is covered in our documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_fixing-npm-not-installed-warning-for-automatic-type-acquisition

For the individual points:

1. Yes VS Code requires that you bring your own version of npm. We don't ship with one because not all users will need it and the majority of js devs who do will already have a copy installed. We are tracking moving ATA off of npm [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16159)
2. This message likely showed up when you did something to trigger ATA. This could be as simple as opening a JS file with an `import` or `require`
3. Set `"typescript.disableAutomaticTypeAcquisition": true` to disable ATA and this message. The downside is that you will not get intellisense for some external modules that you use in your JS (unless you manually manage typings)
4. See point 1. We need npm for ATA